# Is there a significant difference between the number of lecture sessions students attend and their final grades?

Tags: statistical-significance, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I have a database with number of sessions students attended and their final grades as Fail, 3, 4 and 5. Which test should I run to find out if there is a relationship between their attendance and final grade?

Answer (score 0):

The grades are [ordinal-data](/questions/tagged/ordinal-data), so you need models that can deal with that. One common model for that is *ordinal logistic regression*, which generalizes "normal" logistic regression to more than two categories which (importantly) are ordered. [This tag wiki contains pointers to resources.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/ordered-logit/info)